# MongoDb and laravel 8.83

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am beginner to php and Laravel and I am trying to build this simple CRUD application using mongodb as the database I am using the https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-laravel-intergration as the tutorial to learn how to do this I am currently getting stuck at the displaying the data in laravel I made a data base into the application using the:

`'mongodb' => [ 'driver' => 'mongodb', 'dsn' => env('DB_URI','mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.npikk.mongodb.net/myappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'),'database' => 'myappdb',],`
the name of the database made is myappdb and the collections name is posts [Database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze4TH.png).
All of this seems fine but when I run the server and go into the post/first-blog-post route I get a `ErrorException Trying to get property 'Title' of non-object file directory`
and also it marks the line 7 in [post.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QghYW.png).
Model post
[post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7rMS.png)
Post Controller
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdUV8.png)
web route
[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mZaV.png)
Why is this happening? Also are there any better resources to make a CRUD application(any simple application) in laravel with mongodb. Because I am trying to learn but finding it difficult to follow with no guide or experience. All opinions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Hi @anshul-raj, is better if you share the code into snippets instead of images, please check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9676887)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging little by little. I like to use the `dd` function and inspect what is in the variable. It could be that you are accessing a property in the collection which does not exist. So before you let your view show the output, just use the `dd()` function first. Something like `dd(the_variable_I_want_to_check)`.

By the way, are you already conversant with MongoDB?
If not, I would advise you take a brief look at a short introduction to MongoDB:
Check it out from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QQGWYe7IDU

If you are okay with MongoDB, try taking a look at this Playlist on Youtube that I found by "Juniors Code Raw"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0Kc3qSrNlE&list=PLdTx40waQWgHIh3Kegr14vvSF-QsRd40J

It is actually just about 7 videos only. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have actually started a different project but a little more simpler and going to work up from there thanks for the resources as well.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad you are still working.
By the way, whenever you want to get started with a new technology or thing, go simple first. Do simple projects like contact list, todo list, before advancing.

Comment: Yeah I did that and I was eventually successful in making a crud application thank you again for all the advice.